# How to get Azure -default budget for each Azure Subscription in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have a list of subscriptions and I need to use powershell in order to fetch the current -default budget which can be existent in each subscription. I'll give you an example here:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB0zo.png)

So far, this is what I did in Powershell

subscriptions = az account list --query [] | ConvertFrom-Json
$subscriptionsCount = $subscriptions.Count
Write-Host "$($subscriptionsCount) total subscriptions excluding Disabled"

foreach($subId in $subscriptions) {

}

Answer (score 0):

You can get the budget details using [Get-AzureSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure.service/get-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) at subscription level.
Below is the script where you can set the subscription level and get the budget details.

```
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $_.SubscriptionId
    Get-AzConsumptionBudget
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]